# Laravel 4 can't access a value of select::db

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm querying DB in laravel 4 but can't access the returned value here is the code :

```
public static function getCityIdByName($cityname){
    $cityid = DB::select( DB::raw(" SELECT id  FROM cities WHERE match(city_name) against('*" .
        $cityname . "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) " ));

    return $cityid;
}
```

so the function returns this `[{"id":1}]` and I need to get value "1", I tried `$cityid->id` and  `$cityid['id']` and `$cityid[0]`  but it all returns an error , also it is not a string , when I echo it, it complains that array is not a string `Array to string conversion`

Comment: You can `var_dump($cityid)` to know what you have. If seems to be an array of objects so you have to loop over it or access to the 1st item $cityid[0]->id

Comment: that is what var_dump give me `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#384 (1) { ["id"]=> int(1) } }`

Comment: but as I mentioned I tried `$cityid->id` and `$cityid['id']` and `$cityid[0]`

Comment: Read what I wrote `$city = $cityid[0];` will return the 1st object of the array then `$city->id` will return the id of this object. You have to use both [0] and ->id

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code :

```
return $cityid[0]->id;
```

thanks to @ Sylwit

Answer (score 0):

Even if it works you can improve it

If you have several results you would take only the first of the array while you would maybe take care of all results.

You can also use `->first()` in your query to get only the first object which will avoid you to use the [0].

An interesting link
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/is-this-match-against-using-relevance-possible